# ELK - date, defined in logstash shows as string in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have the following config file for logstash:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/elk/data/visits.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["estado","tiempo_demora","poblacion","id_poblacion","edad_valor","cp","latitude_corregida","longitud_corregida","patologia","Fecha","id_tipo","id_personal","nasistencias","menor","Geopoint_corregido"]
    }
    date {
        match => ["Fecha","dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm"]
        target => "Fecha"
    }
    mutate {convert => ["nasistencias", "integer"]}
    mutate {convert => ["id_poblacion", "integer"]}
    mutate {convert => ["id_personal", "integer"]}
    mutate {convert => ["id_tipo", "integer"]}
    mutate {convert => ["cp", "integer"]}
    mutate {convert => ["edad_valor", "integer"]}
    mutate {
        convert => { "longitud_corregida" => "float" }
        convert => { "latitude_corregida" => "float" }
    }
    mutate {
      rename => {
          "longitud_corregida" => "[location][lon]"
          "latitude_corregida" => "[location][lat]"
      }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "medicalvisits-%{+dd.MM.YYYY}"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => json_lines
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

From there `Fecha` should have been sent to elasticsearch as `date`, but in kibana, when I try to set it as timestamp, it doesn't appear, and it shows as string:

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your [date pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match) is wrong, the year should be in lowercase: `dd-MM-yyyy`. And also when defining the name of the index in the `elasticsearch` output.

Comment: It appears correctly though: `Fecha 17/10/16 10:05`. I am going to try.

Comment: Whatever is present in that field will not be changed by ES in your source document. It doesn't mean that it was interpreted correctly. In addition, the year is only two digits, not four.

Answer (score 0):

The types in your index patterns are not the same as the types in your index templates (the information actually being stored).

I would suggest to you, that you should overwrite the timestamp with the information sent by your logstash. After all, what's important to you in most cases, is the timestamp of the event, not the timestamp of the time the event was sent to your elasticsearch.

With this being said, why you just dont save your "Fecha" directly into your "@timestamp" by means of "date" filter in logstash. Like this:

```
    date {
    match => ["Fecha","dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm"]
    target => "@timestamp"
    tag_on_failure => ["fallo_filtro_fecha"]
```

Another option if you really need that "Fecha" algonside with @timestamp (not the best idea), and Fecha being of type "date", is to modify your index mapping to change that field type to date. Like this (adjust as necessary):

```
PUT /nombre_de_tu_indice/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "Fecha": {
      "type": "date",
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this change will only affect new indexed indices or a re-indexed one.

Comment: If you define `Fecha` as type date you also need to add the specific `format` `dd-MM-yy HH:mm` otherwise it won't work as it won't match the default date pattern for date fields.

Comment: I did everything you said; `target => @ timestamp` and making `YYYY` lowercase, and it didn't work. I also tried changing the type from dev tools, and I get this error: `"type": "illegal_argument_exception",`
    `"reason": "mapper [Fecha] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [date]"`

Comment: That's just because your date filter is not working properly as it is not matching the provided date. Re-read Val suggestions and apply. Also, try to add the tag_on_failure to see the failed entries after you reprocess them.